# Sticky piston not dropping block after one-tick pulse on some y-axis values

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I discovered this bug where a sticky piston won't spit out its block when a 1 tick pulse is passed on the block over it. It causes the piston NOT to spit out its block on even -y axis values and on all +y axis values. the sticky piston DOES spit out the block on odd -y axis values. Here is a video of it, I have opened the F3 screen during the video so that you can see what the position of the piston is in the "Targeted block:" part of the F3 menu. I am playing in Minecraft version 1.18.2. No mods.

I know this has something to do with Quasiconnectivity but I don't know how or why, and something to do with directional features (similar to some directional 0 tick pulse generators). How and why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, the dust that powers the piston diagonally gets depowered last. The piston only gets updated and finds this when the b36 of its piston head finalizes.

Redstone dust update order is locational and unpredictable. See MC-11193.

Comment: Oh ok,thank you! Do you think this could be useful in some circuits as the piston won't spit out it's block?

Comment: @Feraminecarts It might come in handy in some very specific wiring situations, but the answer I would say still remains no. Technical players will avoid redstone dust altogether, not just for its locational behaviour, but also because of the lag it causes. And the correlation between odd/even values and the update order that you observe here may not even hold everywhere.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot! I had asked this question on many platforms, but didn't get an answer, so I really appreciate your answer.☺️

Comment: The best way to find out about those things is getting in touch with the technical minecraft community over discord. Scicraft discord, TMC discord, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this'll really help in the future!